# taberror-inconsistent use of tabs and space

Tags: python, python-3.x

i'm having problem at (return not alternating).The error is 'inconsistent use of spaces'.Could anyone pls help me.
I tried using proper amount of tabs and spaces but still the problem persists.

```
def alternating(list):
  listDifference = []
  if list == []:
    return True
  alternating = True
  lPos = 0
  rPos = 1
  #appends the difference between values to a new lis
  while (lPos < len(list)-1) and (rPos < len(list)):
    listDifference.append(list[lPos] - list[rPos])
    lPos += 1
    rPos += 1
  #resets the position
  lPos,rPos = 0,1
  #checks whether values are alternating or not
  while (lPos < len(listDifference)-1) and (rPos < len(listDifference)):
    if listDifference[lPos] < 0:
      if listDifference[rPos] > 0:
        lPos += 1
        rPos += 1
      else:
        return not alternating
    elif listDifference[lPos] > 0:
      if listDifference[rPos] < 0:
        lPos += 1
        rPos += 1
      else:
        return not alternating
  return alternating
```

Comment: You need to use *either* tabs or spaces. In Python 3 you can't use both.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are using both tabs and spaces which gives and error, soy you need to use only tabs or only spaces.